# Epoch/Unix timestamp (in ms) to Datetime in Razor View

Tags: c#, datetime, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, epoch

I have a .Net Core MVC project, in which I am using [pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page) as defined pr. Microsoft Documentation.

As this is the case and since my database timestamp is in Epoch I need to convert the timestamp to a datetime object as it is used for a table in my Razor View. The table is created as follows:

```
@model PaginatedList<MSPFrontend.Tripmetadata>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Trip Id</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Avg Speed</th>
                <th>Distance</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr class="trip" data-id="@item.Tripid" data-url="@Url.Action("TripMapping", "Trip")">
                    <td>@item.Tripid</td>
                    <td>@item.Starttimestamp</td>
                    <td>@item.Endtimestamp</td>
                    <td>@item.Duration</td>
                    <td>@item.AvgSpeed knots</td>
                    <td>@item.Distance km</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My model looks as follows:

```
public partial class Tripmetadata
{
    public Tripmetadata()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int Tripid { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Start Timestamp")]
    public long? Starttimestamp { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End Timestamp")]
    public long? Endtimestamp { get; set; }

    public long? Duration { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Average Speed")]
    public decimal? AvgSpeed { get; set; }

    public decimal? Distance { get; set; }
}
```

I previously used a ViewModel to take care of this, but as pr. Microsoft Pagination docs the pagination needs me to use my model as it requests the data when I scroll through the pagination.

I thought it would be possible to do something like:

```
<td>@new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddMilliseconds(@Convert.ToDouble(@item.Starttimestamp))</td>
```

But I get the following when I try:

```
jquery.js:9566 GET http://localhost:1048/Trip/TripTable 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find my solution which was actually really simple.

Inside my `@foreach(var item in Model)` I can do my conversions, even though it might not be the best way to do it.

I ended up having the following in my view:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @{ 
                    var headerItem = Model[1];
                }
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => headerItem.Tripid)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => headerItem.Starttimestamp)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => headerItem.Endtimestamp)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => headerItem.Duration)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => headerItem.AvgSpeed)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => headerItem.Distance)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var item in Model)
            {
                var startTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(@item.Starttimestamp));
                var endTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(@item.Endtimestamp));
                double diff = Convert.ToDouble(item.Endtimestamp) - Convert.ToDouble(item.Starttimestamp);
                var duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(diff);
                var avgSpeed = Math.Truncate(100 * Convert.ToDecimal(item.AvgSpeed)) / 100;
                var distance = Math.Truncate(100 * Convert.ToDecimal(item.Distance)) / 100;
                <tr class="trip" data-id="@item.Tripid" data-url="@Url.Action("TripMapping", "Trip")">
                    <td>@item.Tripid</td>
                    <td>@startTime</td>
                    <td>@endTime</td>
                    <td>@duration</td>
                    <td>@avgSpeed knots</td>
                    <td>@distance km</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The part under my tabel header is something that allowed me to define my headers in my model. As follows:

```
public partial class Tripmetadata
{
    public Tripmetadata()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Trip ID")]
    public int Tripid { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Start Timestamp")]
    public long? Starttimestamp { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End Timestamp")]
    public long? Endtimestamp { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Duration")]
    public long? Duration { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Average Speed")]
    public decimal? AvgSpeed { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Distance")]
    public decimal? Distance { get; set; }

}
```